# Dynamically assigning tasks to a Task array for Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll to process

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I've been playing around with the Samples for Parallel Programming with the .NET Framework located [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/samples-for-parallel-programming-with-the-net-framework-4/), and learning a bunch of really great things.

Specifically I'm trying to build a simple program that pulls in a list of rss feeds and then parses out specific information.

In the solution, `AsyncDownload_CSharp`, it provides a number of examples of how to download asynchronously. I've got a pretty decent understanding of the following piece of code:

```
// Concurrent async requests
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new []
{
    Download("http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam"),
    Download("http://blogs.msdn.com/nativeconcurrency"),
    Download("http://exampleexampleexample.com"), // will fail
    Download("http://msdn.com/concurrency"),
    Download("http://bing.com")
}, ConcurrentTasksCompleted).Wait();
```

The code above has the list of Tasks hard code and I've been trying to figure out how would I go about generating that list of Tasks dynamically where I assign the value of url at runtime either through a `foreach` loop or some other repeat loop.

The code I came up with to build the list of Tasks dynamically and pass it to the `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll looks` like this:

```
private void btnFeeds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] urls = new[] { "http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam",
        "http://msdn.com/concurrency", "http://bing.com" };
    List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

    foreach (string url in urls)
    {
        tasks.Add(Download(url));
    }
    
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, ConcurrentTasksCompleted).Wait();

}
```

Unfortunately, when I step through the debugger not only do I see the Tasks list being built but as they're being added to the tasks list but I also see them being executed before being passed to the `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll`.

I'm thinking I need to use a lambda expression, instead of that `foreach` loop, to pass each of these to the `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll`. Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time figuring out how the url for the task is applied using the lambda expression.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible, so any suggestions, pointers, or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

because you are using method `DownLoad(url)` to create a task object. in the `DownLoad(url)` method, the task actually had already been started, you can check code in ParallelExtensionsExtras/Extensions/EAP/WebClientExtensions.cs

```
 /// <summary>Downloads the resource with the specified URI as a byte array, asynchronously.</summary> 
    /// <param name="webClient">The WebClient.</param> 
    /// <param name="address">The URI from which to download data.</param> 
    /// <returns>A Task that contains the downloaded data.</returns> 
    public static Task<byte[]> DownloadDataTask(this WebClient webClient, string address) 
    { 
        return DownloadDataTask(webClient, new Uri(address)); 
    } 

    /// <summary>Downloads the resource with the specified URI as a byte array, asynchronously.</summary> 
    /// <param name="webClient">The WebClient.</param> 
    /// <param name="address">The URI from which to download data.</param> 
    /// <returns>A Task that contains the downloaded data.</returns> 
    public static Task<byte[]> DownloadDataTask(this WebClient webClient, Uri address) 
    { 
        // Create the task to be returned 
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>(address); 

        // Setup the callback event handler 
        DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler handler = null; 
        handler = (sender, e) => EAPCommon.HandleCompletion(tcs, e, () => e.Result, () => webClient.DownloadDataCompleted -= handler); 
        webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += handler; 

        // Start the async work 
        try 
        { 
            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(address, tcs); 
        } 
        catch(Exception exc) 
        { 
            // If something goes wrong kicking off the async work, 
            // unregister the callback and cancel the created task 
            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted -= handler; 
            tcs.TrySetException(exc); 
        } 

        // Return the task that represents the async operation 
        return tcs.Task; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized the issue you pointed out after posting. I resolved the issue by doing this

            `List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

            foreach (string url in urls)
            {
                Task<string> task = Download(url);
                tasks.Add(task);
            }

            Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), ConcurrentTasksCompleted);`